# Table heights in Dreamweaver, Trouble setting table height using <p style

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am working on an email signature in dreamweaver using a table. When I added the < p =style tag to set my font size, color, etc., my table heights changed and I can't find a way to make them shorter again so that the text is properly stacked. I tried a couple solutions I found here on stack overflow but they don't seem to work. The problem is that the height of the tables are creating to much space between each line of text. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Here is what the code looks like for the table rows:

```
 <tr>
  <td colspan="5"> <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 12px;"> Best regards, </p></td>
</tr>
<tr> </tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="5"><p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 15px;">
      <strong>Name Lastname</strong></p></td>
</tr>
<tr> </tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="5"><p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 12px;">Title here</p> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

What is the correct way to change the table height within this code?

Comment: do u have it in jsfiddle? would be easy to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the line-height of the text. When you increase the font-size, the line-height increases as per the font-size.

```html
<tr>
  <td colspan="5"> <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 12px; line-height: 5px;"> Best regards, </p></td>
</tr>
<tr> </tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="5"><p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 15px; line-height: 5px;">
      <strong>Name Lastname</strong></p></td>
</tr>
<tr> </tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="5"><p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 12px; line-height: 5px;">Title here</p> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
```